# Is there a way to use multiple tables in Looker dashboard model?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

Can a dashboard be created using multiple not-joined snowflake tables in Looker model?

There is a requirement to get data from different tables in one dashboard

Comment: one dashboard or one Look?

Answer (score 1):

A dashboard can be made up by connecting to different/non joined models.  When creating each visual (chart / graph / data table) on the dashboard, you will choose the model to use.  A single visual has a one to one relationship with a model, but a dashboard can be driven by multiple models

If filtering occurs at a dashboard level, you'll need to be mindful if / how the filters potentially interact between models.